# How to make form generated when choosing radio button using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter

Hi everyone i want to asking how to make a form generated when i choose the option using checkbox or radio button. the form will appear when i choose the option button(manager) and if i choose the option(admin) the form will not appear. can someone give the sample code with javascript or can share the link so i can refer to. for example what i try to do is, i have a form which is user need to fill up

---

1. full name
2. address
3. user type(radio button)

   - admin
   - manager

when user choose as a manager the form will automatically appear and ask for fill more form like

---

4. location store
5. how many staff u have
6. store name

---

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes i try to make some research, and the solution i get is using javascript right. but i dont get any sample which is i can refer and learn. may be my searching keyword ar wrong..

Comment: [toggle element with radio button](https://www.google.se/search?source=hp&q=toggle+element+with+radio+button&oq=toggle+element+with+radio+button&gs_l=psy-ab.3...792.792.0.1223.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.z34OaATLwB4)

Comment: Call javascript function on radio button select. check if selected value is manager. If yes show form.

Comment: @Endless thanks bro, i got it!! helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
 $("#usertype").hide();
 $('#chkuser').change(function () {
                                repeatCheck('chkuser');
                            });


function repeatCheck(valCheck) {
                            if ($('#' + valCheck).is(':checked') === true) {
                                $("#usertype").show();
                            } else {
                                $("#usertype").hide();
                            }
                            ;
                        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Usertype<input type="checkbox" name="chkuser"  id="chkuser">

<div id="usertype" class="form-group" >
                                                           

                                                            <div class="col-md-9">

                                                                <input type="checkbox">manager</input>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" >admin</input>
                                                                                         
                                                                


                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load jquery into header file

`<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jqueryui-1.10.3.min.js' ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>`

form

```
 <div class="form-group" id="input_fields">
    <label for="user_type" class="col-sm-3 control-label">User Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <select id="test" name="user_type"  class="form-control">
    <option value="partner">Administrator</option>
    <option value="referral">Referral</option><option 
    <option value="Admin">User</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#test").change( function(){
     if($("#test").val() == "referral" )
    {
    $("#input_fields").append('<div class="form-group" id = "toggle"><div  class="form-group">'+
    '<label for="percentage" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Percentage</label>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-6">'+
    '<input type="text" name="percentage" id="percentage" class="form-control" placeholder=" Referral commission ">'+
    '<span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('percentage'); ?></span>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-3"><p class="help-block">Percentage in %</p></div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="form-group" id = "toggle" >'+
    '<label for="bank_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bank Name</label>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-6">'+
    '<select  name="user_type"  class="form-control">'+
    '<option value="Malayan Banking Berhad">Malayan Banking Berhad</option>'+
    '<option value="CIMB Bank Berhad">CIMB Bank Berhad</option>'+
    '<option value="Public Bank Berhad">Public Bank Berhad</option>'+
    '<option value="RHB Bank Berhad">RHB Bank Berhad</option>'+
    '<option value="Hong Leong Bank Berhad">Hong Leong Bank Berhad</option>'+
    '<option value="AmBank (M) Berhad">AmBank (M) Berhad</option>'+
    '<option value="Alliance Bank Malaysia Berhad">Alliance Bank Malaysia Berhad</option>'+
    '<option value="Bank Rakyat">Bank Rakyat</option>'+
    '<option value="OCBC Bank (Malaysia)">OCBC Bank (Malaysia)</option>'+
    '<option value="HSBC Bank Malaysia">HSBC Bank Malaysia</option>'+

    '</select>'+

    '</div>'+

    '</div>'+
    '<div class="form-group" id = "toggle" >'+
    '<label for="bank_acc_info" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bank Account Information</label>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-6">'+
    '<input type="text" name="bank_acc_info" id="bank_acc_info" class="form-control" placeholder="Bank Account Information">'+
                                                        '<span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('bank_acc_info'); ?></span>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-3"><p class="help-block">Bank Number</p></div>'+
    '</div></div>');
    }
    else
    {
    $("#toggle").remove();
    }
     });
    });
```

Here what i found and i test it, everything go smooth.